# High CPU usage of "NT Kernel & System" process while Chrome playing YouTube video

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, cpu, youtube

I have a headache from searching for solution of my problem.

Everytime when I open **Google Chrome** and **any YouTube video** (doesn't matter if Flash or HTML5), system process named "**NT Kernel & System**" goes to costume about **17% of all my CPU** performance.

It assumes to 100% of 1 core of all 8 cores.

[image]

When I close the YouTube tab, the process immediatelly drops to 0~2% which seems to be OK.

PC specs:

- ASUS R500V
- Intel Core i7-3610QM @ 2.30 GHz
- 8 GB RAM

SW:

- Windows 7 SP1 Home Premium 64-bit
- Google Chrome 40.0.2214.91 m 64-bit

And in the last stats from Chrome task manager:

[image]

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the high CPU usaage (30 - 60s): http://pastebin.com/4h2ySm1V and share it. I'll take a look at it and try to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for instructions, here is the file: https://mega.co.nz/#!wUs3CBDD!DDLqlXIIbqzzZZ-jBQ8V7gAkrMJAZ4p1p1O8syNirWQ
I'm not sure if I did it right but hope so. Please let me know.. Thanks.

Comment: the trace is corrupted. Set the value after **-buffersize**  to **4096** and capture a new trace.

Comment: Ok next try: https://mega.co.nz/#!MYUC0bBS!Ei4-5D69gwyFTycIXAap_sPda284yq3f6DlxKtCYc24

Comment: the trace is too short (only 8seconds). HEre the system uses 1.8% and this is fine. Capture a new one which shows the high usage and also close the YT tab to show the drop in CPU usage

Comment: I have the same issue just now with Chrome version 40.0.2214.93

Comment: @TimBJames also provide a xperf trace

Comment: @Martin have you captured a new trace?

Comment: Martin - I have same issue. Lenovo W540, i7-4800MQ, Quadro K2100M.  Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit 40.0.2214.115 m. Thanks for your fix. @magicandre1981 do you still want a trace? Will be happy to provide if so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I solved it.

I unchecked "**use hardware acceleration when available**". Now it's everything faster and consumes lower CPU.

[image]

Comment: report this issue in the Chrome Bugtracker, so that the Chrome Team can fix it.

Comment: I can confirm the fix as well.

Answer (score -1):

Had same problem with Win7 Pro.
I uninstalled Intel® Rapid Storage Technology drivers and the problem was solved.